# Track progress for loading content in Suspense

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the experimental hook introduced in React recently, called the Suspense.

I pass a child component within the Suspense tag that gets loaded in background while it shows the fallback component that is declared.

Trying to find a way to track the progress(in %), probably a prop that uses a callback as it's value and update the progress each time it is called after a specific interval.

Something like the following code:

```
function test(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading</h1>} onProgress={(progress) => console.log(`Progress percentage value = ${progress}`)} />
                <div>
                    // Some axios or any other async call within.
                </div>
           </Suspense>
        </div>
    )
}
```